# When i use setValue command and pass string value "Oct (10)" it is setting only "Oct 10)" does anyone know why?

Tags: webdriver, cucumber

When i use setValue command and pass string value "Oct (10)" it is setting only "Oct 10)" does anyone know why?

I tired escaping '(' but no luck.

any know issues with setValue command in webdriver

i am using it cucumber-js

code, this is how i am using setValue, all values are entered into the input fields except month where it enters value as "Oct 10)" instead of "Oct (10)"

{code}

```
this.browser
    .setValue(//input[class='selectDate'],"10")
    .setValue(//input[class='selectMonth'],"Oct (10)")
    .setValue(//input[class='selectYear'],"1990")
```

{code}

Comment: pasting the real snippet of code how you do it and how you get the data back will help others to help you. At this stage, it is just guessing game...

Comment: Thanks for update. One more question - what language are you using? Java? And what is "this" referring to? WebElement?

Comment: Hi, I am using javascript, yes this is referring to a webelement